# Unwrap a single case union 'in place'

Tags: f#

I've got this beautiful piece of F# code, mapping a Pizza to a PizzaModel:

```
type Cheese = Cheese of string

type Pizza 
{
    Name: string
    Cheese: Cheese
}

type PizzaModel =
{
    PizzaName : string
    Cheese: string
    Toppings: string
}

let mapPizza pizza = 
    let (Cheese c) = pizza.Cheese
    { PizzaName = pizza.Name; Cheese = c}
```

Is it possible to write this different, can I unwrap Cheese in place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me some time to figure out what your type definitions might be. I got your code to compile with the following, so I'm assuming that's what you have:

```
type Cheese = Cheese of bool
type CheesePizza = { PizzaName : string; Cheese : bool }
type Pizza = { Name : string; Cheese : Cheese}
```

I don't think there is a way to unwrap the cheese inline on the last line of your function, but you can unwrap both the name and the cheese in a pattern on the first line:

```
let mapPizza { Cheese = Cheese c; Name = name } = 
    { PizzaName = name; Cheese = c}
```

This pattern matches on the argument and extracts the cheese using a nested pattern.

**EDIT** Another approach would be to modify the `Cheese` type and add a member that lets you easily access the wrapped value. This can be done quite easily:

```
type Cheese = 
    | Cheese of string
    member x.Value = let (Cheese v) = x in v
```

Now you can unwrap the value using `pizza.Cheese.Value` inline:

```
let mapPizza pizza = 
    { PizzaName = pizza.Name; Cheese = pizza.Cheese.Value }
```

Comment: I edited my post, but that won't change your answer much I suppose?

Comment: @Mulder You're right - the answer is still the same. To make your updated code compile, I think you need to remove `Toppings` and define `PizzaModel` _before_ `Pizza` (otherwise the compiler uses the member access `pizza.Cheese` to infer that the argument is `PizzaModel`, not `Pizza`)